# how to get array value in foreach using Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using **Laravel5.0** i'm facing with a problem to using **foreach**  with **$key=>$values** and point to index and get it values as below function.

Here is my Data

```
array (size=1)
  5 => int 0
int 197001
array (size=5)
  1 => float 106060
  0 => float 0
  3 => float 0
  2 => float 0
  4 => int 7

int 201401
array (size=5)
  0 => float 268.092
  3 => float 798.908
  2 => float 0
  1 => float 236988
  4 => int 16

int 201402
array (size=5)
  0 => float 2515.874
  3 => float 4496.126
  2 => float 0
  1 => float 481535
  4 => int 32
```

Here is my code:
I want to short and fetch the values form **$values** variable and get index by **$key**

```
 <?php

    $temp1 = 0.00;
    $repayment_schedule =array_sort($repayment_schedule,function($value,$key){
           return $key;
       });
    $temp2 = 0.00;
       $repayment_actual = array_sort($repayment_actual,function($value,$key){
           return $key;
       });
      ?>
     @if(!empty($repayment_schedule))
      <?php
        $arr_keys = array_keys($repayment_schedule);
            $last_key = end($arr_keys);
      ?>
     @foreach($repayment_schedule as $key=>$value)
       <?PHP echo $value[2]; ?><br/>
       <?PHP var_dump($value); ?><br/>
       <?PHP var_dump($key); ?>

   @endforeach
  @endif
```

This is my errors type
ErrorException in cc14ec3e6b08763053170f56b5633aaf line 196:
Undefined offset: 2

Comment: Your parent array size is only `1` and you are using `$value[2]` that's why it gives you `Undefined offset: 2`

Comment: I can't event 0 1 2,3 5

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: It is too much code but I can't put here did you know some website allow me to keep should code and send that line to you

Comment: Dear Friends

Please It is in line 195
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/216b5d4533b149c50687